# Bonsai leaves turning brown and dropping

Tags: leaves, bonsai

I have a chinese elm bonsai tree, iv had it since febuary. At first it was goin great.. getting lots of new shoots, lots of new leaves.. it was looking green and bushy! My leaves are turning brown and dropping and i also have shoots that only have leaves at the end of the shoots.. the rest fell off! Does anyone have any ideas as to where in going wrong? I keep it indoors on a windowsill that gets plenty of light from early morning till it goes dark! Its has roughly 5hrs direct early morning sun. I water the plant every 2-3 days i just get where iv gone wrong.. as i said it was very green and bushy for a while now not so much! Can iver trimming cause brown leaves, or mayb to much fertilizer?? And help would be great

Comment: Welcome to G&L! Could you post a few pictures of your Bonsai? My first suggestion would be to keep it outside, remember it's a tree.

Comment: I keep trying to upload a pic but it wont let me, but iv done what you suggested and put it outside, will see if that makes the difference! There is new little bulbs coming on the shoots from where the brown ones fell off so i know the tree isnt dead! Its just that the leaves are going brown and dropping about a week after they open up.